# No Menu ActionBar, como permitir que o ícone de um item seja sempre visível, e o texto somente quando houver espaço?

Tags: android, actionbar

Estou tentando e pesquisando, a algum tempo a possibilidade de ter um comportamento em meu [Menu do `ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html), da seguinte forma para alguns items:

- Ícone (`android:icon`): sempre visível no `ActionBar`;
- Texto (`android:title`): somente visível se houver espaço;

**O que já tentei:**

**Tentativa 1:**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/btn_add"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
// Resultado: Mostra o item somente se houver espaço, mas o ícone juntamente com o texto
```

**Tentativa 2:**

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
// Resultado: Mostra o item somente se houver espaço, mas somente ícone sem o texto
```

**Tentativa 3:**

```
android:showAsAction="always"
// Resultado: Mostra o item sempre, mas somente o ícone
```

**Tentativa 4:**

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
// Resultado: Mostra o item sempre, mas o ícone juntamente com o texto
```

**O que gostaria de fazer:**

Para efeito de demonstração o que eu pretenderia seria algo similar a isso (não há isso, obviamente):

```
// always|withIcon (sempre ícone) e ifRoom|withText (se houver espaço com texto)
android:showAsAction="always|withIcon|ifRoom|withText"
```

Então há alguma alternativa para obter esse comportamento em um item de menu do `ActionBar`?

Comment: Fernando, acho que com a API padrão não é possível fazer. Acho que com o `Toolbar` e usando `Views` normais e manipulando visibilidade e calculando espaço (vai acabar sendo bem chato).

Comment: Entendo, @Wakim. É que isso não parece fazer muito sentido, pois se tenho um ícone e um titulo para o botão, e há espaço no `ActionBar`, por que não exibir o ícone e title? Mas isso não é crucial para minha aplicação. Só postei aqui para desencargo mesmo, pois perdi algum tempo pesquisando sobre isso e nada. Assim posso repassar (aos superiores) que isso não é suportado pela API padrão/nativa, se for o caso. (E não pretendo fazer "gambiarras" em meu `ActionBar` padrão, hehe).

Comment: É, como você disse tem a configuração de ícone+texto, mas não tem `if espaco pra icone+texto then icone+texto else if espaco then icone else esconde icone`, esse é o problema, se é o que eu entendi do use case.

Comment: @Wakim, na verdade o algorítimo seria esse: `if espaco para icone+texto then icone+texto else if espaco para icone then icone else esconde icone+texto and add texto action overflow`. Entendeu?

Comment: Hmm, entendi... Esse caso não tem mesmo, só fazendo na "mão" e com um bom esforço... Não sei se sobreescrevendo a classe do `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` teria como fazer isso, no método que constrói o menu.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível atribuir mais de um tipo "showAsAction" em um único item de menu. Ao tentar fazer isso, a seguinte exception é lançada:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS,SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM, and SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER are mutually exclusive.
```

Talvez você consiga um efeito parecido utilizando um item para texto e outro item para o icone e ir alternando a visibilidade diretamente no código, por exemplo: Quando o dispostivo está na horizontal (visão mais ampla da action bar), coloque o icone para ficar invisível e o texto para ficar visível e quando o dispositivo estiver na vertical (visão menos ampla da action bar), faça o contrário.

De qualquer forma, não acho que isso seria fácil de fazer e também não daria o efeito real desejado, mas infelizmente não conheço uma outra alternativa.

**OBS.: Procure sempre usar os padrões de UI indicados/fornecidos pelas APIs do Android, pois isso padroniza os aplicativos e a experiencia do usuário, que fica mais rápida, uma vez que ele não precisa ficar "descobrindo" as funções que o aplicativo fornece clicando em várias opções até acertar. E lembre-se, sempre utilize ícones que sejam auto-descritivos: lupa = realizar busca, disquete = salvar, sinal de + = adicionar/criar, etc, pois isso elimina a necessidade de colocar um texto.**